# Dependent targets executed twice if two targets in command line

Tags: ant

I have an Ant build file with dependencies as follow:

```xml
<target name="resolve">
  ....
</target>

<target name="compile" depends="resolve">
  ....
</target>

<target name="ship" depends="compile">
  ....
</target>
```

When invoking only the ship target with `ant ship`, only needed target are executed in the right order: `[resolve>compile>ship]`.

The issue is when directly invoking two targets on the command line.
By executing `ant compile ship`, the output is `[resolve > compile > resolve > compile > ship]`. I cannot understand the logic chosen to execute some dependencies twice.

How can I force Ant to never execute a target twice ? With a very complex build file, I cannot always run the intended command with a single target.

Comment: The output is that. But does the tasks in `resolve` and `compile` really executed twice? Plz check again.

Comment: Yes, the `resolve` and `compile` targets are execute twice. The issue is implementation of resolve invokes `<ivy:configure ... />`, which does not accept to be call more than once in a build.

Comment: The dependency tree doesn't take multiple command line targets into account. This is considered a feature of Ant. Some explanation and workarounds can be found here: http://grokbase.com/t/ant/user/021bznjdy9/multiple-targets-on-command-line